# mlkit ocr with react native and expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ocr, image-recognition, firebase-mlkit

i have an upcoming project to build an app that has some kind of character recognition in it i have chose react native with expo and mlkit and i followed the documentation carefully but i always get the following error:
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'detectFromUri')
**can someone help me i've been trying to find a solution for days**

````
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Image, Button } from 'react-native';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import MlkitOcr from 'react-native-mlkit-ocr';
function App() {
  // The path of the picked image
  const [pickedImagePath, setPickedImagePath] = useState('');
  const [result,setResult] = useState("");

  // This function is triggered when the "Select an image" button pressed
  const showImagePicker = async () => {
    // Ask the user for the permission to access the media library 
    const permissionResult = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();

    if (permissionResult.granted === false) {
      alert("You've refused to allow this appp to access your photos!");
      return;
    }
    const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync();
    // Explore the result
    console.log(result);

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      setPickedImagePath(result.uri);
      console.log(result.uri);
    }
  }
  const finallyOcr = async    () => {
    const resultFromUri = await MlkitOcr?.detectFromUri(pickedImagePath);}

  // This function is triggered when the "Open camera" button pressed
  const openCamera = async () => {
    // Ask the user for the permission to access the camera
    const permissionResult = await ImagePicker.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();

    if (permissionResult.granted === false) {
      alert("You've refused to allow this appp to access your camera!");
      return;
    }

    const result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync();

    // Explore the result
    console.log(result);

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      setPickedImagePath(result.uri);
      console.log(result.uri);
    }
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <Button onPress={showImagePicker} title="Select an image" />
        <Button onPress={openCamera} title="Open camera" />
      </View>

      <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
        {
          pickedImagePath !== '' && <Image
            source={{ uri: pickedImagePath }}
            style={styles.image}
          />
        }
      </View>
      <Button onPress={finallyOcr} title="OCR" />
    </View>
  );
}

export default App;

// Kindacode.com
// Just some styles
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    width: 400,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-around'
  },
  imageContainer: {
    padding: 30
  },
  image: {
    width: 400,
    height: 300,
    resizeMode: 'cover'
  }
});```
````

Comment: ```MlkitOcr``` is returning ```undefined```

Answer (score 0):

ImagePicker returns a response object within an array, so before you pass it to MLKit for processing, you have to correctly access the property you want.

So `result.uri` should be updated to `result.assets[0].uri`